# Find the domain of this function in the x,y,z graph

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Find the domain of this function in set notation:

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+4}}v$

$v=y-x$

Could I say that $x^2+y^2+4 \geq 0$ and $y-x \geq 0$ and based off those statements put that into set notation? and get:

$D= \{(x,y)|x^2+y^2+4 \neq 0$ and $y-x \neq 0\}$

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on writing mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you want to avoid in the domain of $f$.

1) $x^2+y^2+4<0$

2) $0=v = y-x$

But $x^2+y^2 +4 \geq 4 >0$ so this shouldn't be a problem. However if $x=y$ then $v=0$ so the domain is $D=\{(x,y)\mid x \neq y\}$.

**Edit** Here is a "picture" of $D$ as asked in the comment. $D$ is basically everything except the points that are on the red line. Note that this picture only represents a little part of $D$ since it is an unbounded domain (e.g. $(10^{2137612},\pi)$ belongs to $D$ but is not on the picture).

[image]

Comment: So if I was to try and sketch a picture of the domain, would that even be possible?

Comment: @Overclock Yes a picture is somehow possible with a bit of imagination in the sens that the domain is $\Bbb R^2$ but a line (which is infinitely thin). I can post a "drawing" if you wish.

Comment: could you? I'm curious how that would look

Comment: @Overclock done :).

Answer (score 1):

Since $v \neq 0$ by definition, then $y-x \neq 0$ ---> $y \neq x$. Therefore, the line y= x is excluded from the domain of f. Also, since $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+4}\geq 0$ and $y \neq x$,  $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+4}$. So the domain is $ D = \{(x,y)| \sqrt{x^2+y^2+4}\geq 0$ where $y\neq x$}  Surb gives an excellent sketch of the domain above in his/her reply.

Comment: Note that $x^2 + 4 = (x + 2i)(x - 2i)$.  You are confusing $x^2 + 4$ with $x^2 - 4 = (x + 2)(x - 2)$.

Comment: That's what happens when you try and rush an answer-you make idiotic mistakes like that. I fixed it,but too late.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see this

$$x^2+y^2+4 \geq 4 >0,\quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}. $$